# How to delete Seq[String] from JsObject?

Tags: scala, play-json

```
private def updateData(
  oldData: Seq[Data], 
  authorised: Boolean, 
  removeItemList: Seq[String]
): Seq[Data] = {
    if (!authorised) {
      oldData.map { data =>
        val props: Option[JsObject] = data.props.map { 
          props => props.as[JsObject] - removeItemList(0) - removeItemList(1) - removeItemList(2) 
        }
        data.copy(props = props)
      }
    } else {
      oldData
    }
  }
```

Can we improve this code? so it's work with removeItemList length > 3.

Comment: There is a lot of irrelevant code here  (e.g. `authorised` test), and some of the types are not defined. It would really help if you just showed the actual operation you are trying to perform as a simple function including the relevant types.

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: @Yann import play.api.libs.json.JsObject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to, for every item in `removeItemList`, remove it from the `JsObject` which resulted from the last removal.

This is the very definition of a `fold`:

```
removeItemList.foldLeft(props.as[JsObject]) { (jso, v) => jso - v }
```

- we use `props.as[JsObject]` as the start value
- for every item in `removeItemList`, we combine it with the current value with the combining function
- the combining function removes the item from the current value